# raw_id_fields raising error Related Field got invalid lookup: icontains

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I don't know why but django-admin, raw_id_fields is returning me an related field error. I'll explain what I've done and the different methods I tried without result.

For this particular case I have 5 different models:

- System: Orphan
- Concept: Orphan
- Extract: Related with System, 1 Extract is a children of 1 system, 1 system has many Extracts
- Mapping: Related with Systems twice: A mapping is the relation between two systems one is origin and the other is the destination
- MappingDestinationExtractConcept: Within a mapping, specific extracts of the destination system will be "mapped" for a given concept.

I have no problems using raw id in all of the models but in the `Mapping DestinationExtractConcept` Model which returns the infamous icontains error when using the admin search engine.

```
# Models.py
class System(models.Model):
    system_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False, verbose_name='System')
    version = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, verbose_name='Version')

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('system_name', 'version'),)


class Extract(models.Model):
    extract_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False, verbose_name='Extract Name')
    system = models.ForeignKey(System, related_name='extracts', on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='System')

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Mapping of {} into {}'.format(self.mapping_system, self.destination_system)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('extract_name', 'system'),)


class Mapping(models.Model):
    destination_system = models.ForeignKey(System, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='mappings',
                                           verbose_name='Destination System')
    mapping_system = models.ForeignKey(System, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='maps_into',
                                       verbose_name='Input System')
    mapping_description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
    unique_together = (('mapping', 'destination_extract', 'mapping_concept'),)


class MappingTargetTableConceptSources(models.Model):
    mapping_target_table_concept = models.ForeignKey(MappingTargetTableConcept, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                                 related_name='is_used', verbose_name='Mapping Concept')
    destination = models.ForeignKey(Extract, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Source Table')

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('mapping_target_table_concept', 'source', ),)
```

The in the `admin.py`, I simply want to call to raw id in the destination extract of the MappingTargetTableConcept

```
# admin.py
class MappingTargetTableConceptManager(admin.ModelAdmin):
    raw_id_fields = ('destination_extract',)

admin.site.register(MappingTargetTableConcept, MappingTargetTableConceptManager)
```

The admin shows the loupe for searching, and the pop-up shows, but when looking in the pop up for the extract that I want (or anything) it brings. In the console this works `Extract.objects.filter(extract_name__icontains='Contract')`

I tried replacing the raw_id for `raw_id_fields=('destination_extract__extract_name',).. no success

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it.. the problem (or at least the way It got fixed was for the search fields in the related modeladmin of the extract)

I had:

```
class ExtractManager2(admin.ModelAdmin):         
     search_fields = ('system', 'extract_name', 'tech_name', 'description', )
```

When I change this into:

```
class ExtractManager2(admin.ModelAdmin):         
     search_fields = ('extract_name',)
```

It works..